# Can't register my own modules JS and CSS into the module - Prestashop 1.7.8.4

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I cant get my modules CSS and JS to work. The module itself is working correctly, it's turned on, it loads the template file but no matter what I do I just cannot get the css and js to load in.

the css and js are located in:

modules/dksearch/views/js/dksearch.js

modules/dksearch/views/css/dksearch.css

this is the modules php file

```
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')){
exit;
}

class DkSearch extends Module {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->name = "dksearch";
        $this->tab = "front_office_features";
        $this->version = "1.0";
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->ps_version_compliancy = [
            "min" => "1.7",
            "max" => _PS_VERSION_
        ];
        $this->bootstrap = true;
    
        parent::__construct();
    
        $this->displayName = "DKSearch";
        $this->description = "Lorem ipsum";
        $this->confirmUninstall = "Removed";
    }
    
    public function install() {
         return parent::install() && 
         $this->registerHook('registerDKSearch');
         $this->registerHook('actionFrontControllerSetMedia') &&
         Configuration::updateValue('dksearch', 'dksearch');
    }
    
    public function uninstall() : Bool
    {
        return parent::uninstall();
    }
    
    public function hookdisplayDKSearch() {
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/hook/dksearch.tpl');
    }
    
    public function hookActionFrontControllerSetMedia()
    {
        $this->context->controller->registerStylesheet(
            'dksearch-style',
            $this->_path.'views/css/dksearch.css',
            [
                'media' => 'all',
                'priority' => 1000,
            ]
        );
    
        $this->context->controller->registerJavascript(
            'dksearch-javascript',
            $this->_path.'views/js/dksearch.js',
            [
                'position' => 'bottom',
                'priority' => 1000,
            ]
        );
    }

}
```

The hookdisplayDKSearch.tpl file is displayed in header.tpl by {hook h='displayDKSearch'}
I didn't hook ActionFrontControllerSetMedia anywhere in the page i don't know if its necessary.
Im using the classic theme if that's worth noting.

I tried following the steps in the presta shop documentation, youtube guides and google but nothing seemed to work, unless i implemented them incorrectly :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is prestashop now doesn't allow you to register JS and CSS using that hook. You can use displayHeader hook and addJS, addCSS methods.

```php
$this->registerHook('displayHeader');
```

And then

```php
public function hookDisplayHeader() {
    $this->context->controller->addJS("{$this->_path}/views/js/dksearch.js");
    $this->context->controller->addCSS("{$this->_path}/views/css/dksearch.css");
}
```

Remember that you have to reset your module to make registerHook get called inside install() function!

Comment: One tip: if your module, for example gets called in category page only, you don't need to add css and js to the  whole website. One method is to check for the controller name in displayHeader() so you can register Jss and Css only in some controllers. That's important so you don't overweight the website where not needed.

Comment: Much thanks :) Didn't know I have to reset the module. Also I think it should be hookdisplayHeader

Comment: You're welcome! If you need any other help with prestashop feel free to contact me on tg "damiano_mazzara". I know how hard is to figure out prestashop problems without any help. Often the solution, as you have seen, is easier than expected!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help of Damiano Mazzara I've managed to make it work again.

I had to change the install function

```
    public function install() {
     return parent::install() && 
     $this->registerHook('displayDKSearch') &&
     $this->registerHook('displayHeader');
}
```

Then, I changed the hook function with the one provided by Damian and reseted the module in the back office :)

```
    public function hookdisplayHeader() {
    $this->context->controller->addJS("{$this->_path}/views/js/dksearch.js");
    $this->context->controller->addCSS("{$this->_path}/views/css/dksearch.css");
}
```